# Autodetect master/slave proxy for PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, proxy, failover

I have a cluster of master/slave PostgreSQL replication. I am looking for some kind of application that will proxy all the traffic to the master server. In case of fail-over when slave becomes master, I need that software to auto detect the new master. Currently I am using pgpool II, but it has no ability to auto detect which back-end is master. I mean I need to manually change backend1 (slave) to be backend0 (master) in case of master failure.

Please advice.

Comment: You can try it on the application level by checking the query status to the master server, meaning if the query is inserted successfully then it's okay, or else, change the connection to your slave server. This will handle errors in the server and DB levels.

Comment: Make sense. However there are too many third party applications that use the DB and it will be very difficult to do that. That's why I need to have a solution on the service level.

Comment: How is the failover accomplished? manual or automatic?

Answer (score 0):

This requires considerable setup and is described in detail in chapter 8 of the [pgpool 2 documentation](https://www.pgpool.net/docs/latest/en/html/example-cluster.html).

Comment: Yes, it's a solution. However it is too complex configuration for something that can be done using and external script that checks which node is master with a simple select pg_is_in_recovery() query.